# RuntimeError on python Osmnx

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am using openstreetmap for the first time. I have issues on using osmnx library. Here is my code:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA', network_type='drive')
ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

And i got the error :

```
b'No such file or directory'
```

[image]

I am using Anaconda3.6

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSMnx Error: RuntimeError: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179195/osmnx-error-runtimeerror-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked/answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270781/7321942

This is a fiona environment variable issue. See also:

- https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/203
- https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/205
- https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/830

Comment: It's fixed. Thank you very much